# How many non-empty accounts are there?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, accounts, state-trie

I am researching into the statistics of Ethereum and I an looking for a datum of how many non-zero balance account currently exist in Ethereum?

I know that in total 30M of accounts were created but how many accounts of those do have >0 balance?

Answer (score 0):

To my surprise of those 30M accounts only 1% is active:

https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/activeaddresses-btc-eth.html#3m

Less than 400k accounts

Comment: Are you sure that's addresses with a non-zero balance? At the top it says "Number of unique (from or to) addresses per day", which implies it might be the number of accounts _used_ on a given day.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks, good point. it's not the answer to the question, but it is a hint.

Comment: Please note that Bitcoin is UTXO address based system whereas Ethereum is account address based system. Bitcoin creates new addresses for each transaction while Ethereum does not. Comparison is not apples to apples.